# Easy way to get facebook statuses from a particular page in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook

I need to grab the statuses from a Facebook page via PHP to display on the page. I don't want to have people logging in to facebook just for my script to grab the statuses from the page since it is a public page and isn't restricted. I have the Facebook API for PHP in my projects directory but have no idea how to use it to do what I want it to. Could someone give me a code example of how I'd do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really a straight forward task if you follow the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/). Since `/PAGE_ID/feed` requires any valid `access_token`, your app `access_token` is enough to get the data:

1. Open the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=coca-cola/feed) (I'm querying `coca-cola/feed`)
2. Get an [app `access_token`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#app-login) from the [Access Token Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/) and use it instead of yours
3. You're done!

Comment: Only problem is that the access token there expires in an hour. Any way of making it not expire for a month?